# github pull request builder not working

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration

Jenkins error log

```
Sep 10, 2015 11:26:55 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger stop
INFO: Stopping the ghprb trigger for project abc
Sep 10, 2015 11:26:55 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger start
INFO: Starting the ghprb trigger for the abc job; newInstance is true
Sep 10, 2015 11:26:55 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbGitHubAuth getBuilder
WARNING: credentialsId not set for context abc, using anonymous connection
Sep 10, 2015 11:26:57 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbRepository initGhRepository
SEVERE: Could not retrieve GitHub repository named organization/abc (Do you have properly set 'GitHub project' field in job configuration$
java.io.FileNotFoundException: {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
```

In configuration setting Under "Build Triggers" section I have checked "Build when a change is pushed to Github" and "Github Pull Request Builder".
I have also checked "Use github hooks for build triggering"

Under "Manage jenkins" -> "Configure System" -> "Github Pull Request Builder"
I have set auto generated credentials in "credentials" field.

[image]

I have setup webhooks on the github and its working fine for any changes being pushed to the repository but not working for pull request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the auto generated credentials are not working.

```
WARNING: credentialsId not set for context abc, using anonymous connection
```

You need to generate a token on GitHub (https://github.com/settings/tokens). The default scopes should provide the necessary permissions. Then, in the global Jenkins Pull Request Builder configuration, add new credentials using your GitHub user name and the generated token.

Comment: After generating token and pasting it to "Shared secret" field of "GitHub Pull Request Builder" will work ?

Comment: No that field has a different purpose, use the "Credentials" field. And use the "Add" button next to that field to add new credentials. Btw, I'm assuming that your are using a recent version of the Pull Request Builder plugin, e.g. version 1.27.

Comment: yeah it is the recent version. 
Can I left "shared secret" field blank and only add the username and password of a github bot user generated for jenkins ?
As you said in the answer, generate the token but where to put the generated token as there is no field to save the token. There is only shared secret field that is present

Comment: You have to enter the token in the password field.

Comment: Where is password field?  Is there any role of SCM? Should I select git under SCM Sync configuration

Comment: Go to "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" -> "GitHub Pull Request Builder" section. Click the "Add" button next to the "Credentials" field. In the popup window, use the following settings: Kind -> "Username with password", Scope -> "Global (...)", Username -> the GitHub user name, Password -> the GitHub OAuth token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89310/discussion-between-ajeet-khan-and-daspilker).

Comment: I have similar problem but not exactly same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958189/ghprb-plugin-in-jenkins-unable-to-trigger-build . Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Just realized the hard way that 'Shared secret' is auto generated. You don't need to worry about filling it in